# Android - Kotlin - stop for in middle of process

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there is any way to stop for loop in Kotlin in middle of process without using a `break` ?

Example :

```
for (item in items) {
    for (item2 in arrRealmTemp ) {
        if (item.MKT == item2.MKT && item.UPC == item2.UPC ) {
            // I want to stop this (the inner for only ) here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a break? And is this the only restriction?

Comment: because when you use break; in for loop inside for loop its sometime change the pointers location when the fors are huge.

Comment: You can state your reason of not using `break` in your question also.

Comment: @omertamir it changes what? What pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use label in following way.

```
loop@ for (i in 1..100) {
  for (j in 1..100) {
    if (...) break@loop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In *Kotlin* you can use labels and `continue` to be sure to continue with the next iteration of a for loop:

```
loop@ for (item in items) {
    for (item2 in arrRealmTemp ) {
        if (item.MKT == item2.MKT && item.UPC == item2.UPC ) {
            continue@loop
        }
    }
}
```